# Auto Reply to Form Submission

Tags: development, email, form

Is it possible to set up an auto reply to a form submission? If so, how?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The more easy way without coding is to create a workflow with this approach:

- Workflow triggered on item created
- Action "Send Mail"

Hope it will be helpfully.

Comment: When I go to set up the workflow on the Share Point, I do not see an option to Action "Send Mail" . Could this be a setting that the Administrator needs to add to the Share Point or is there something else that I need to do in between the steps?

Comment: Check this links: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNxD82KiUhQ and https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4